# Broadcast on service start?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, broadcasting

Does android send any kind of broadcast when a new service is started/restarted.

underlying reason is i'd like to catch whenever a background service is starting without my knowledge.

any answer to how it's possible, if it is, are appreciated.

EDIT:
I want it to work with all services, not only my own services.

Answer (score 0):

If the background service is in your control then you can use **onBind()** method to get to know that the service is started by **bindService()** and same time you can use **onStartCommand()** method if the service is started by **startService()**....

Answer (score 0):

That mean you want to access system service or what? or service which you have written in your android application?
if you want  to control your service which you have written in your application then as above told you can control it..or if you want to start or stop service when you want then you can create **broadcast receiver** and write **onreceive()** what you want to do.

Comment: do you mean that something is indeed broadcasted ? i'm already using a broadcast receiver to catch the ON_BOOT.